# Почему видео в blob не загружается?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Если вставить прямую ссылку mp4, то все работает, но blob вообще не грузит видео. Как это решить?

```
function App() {
  let file = new Blob(
    ['//cloud.cdnland.in/8b821d83dd0a715238d99fdd4f24e425:2023101104/movies/4ce6c072a43da096c2d56b5c8a4e9c640fd3d1fc/720.mp4'],
    { "type": "video\/mp4" }
  )

  return (
    <video src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} controls></video>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: А почему оно должно загружаться? Ты сделал blob c содержимым `//cloud.cnland....`, а вовсе не загрузит файл с этого урла.

Comment: А как решить это по другому? :)

Comment: Посмотрите на пример тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer#examples

Comment: Не получается у меня ничего :( выдает ошибку Cannot read properties of undefined (reading “addSourceBuffer”)

Comment: Пишите новый вопрос с кодом и ошибками